# If I insert a DIV a second time, it will only overlap and the JS will not work anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a product card for products. This works too, but if I insert a second one, nothing at all works. The cards overlap and the JS does not work anymore ...

```
<div id="make-3D-space">
<div id="product-card">
   <div id="product-front">
      <div class="shadow"></div>
      <img class="img" src="https://www.alfru.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Acerola.jpg" alt="" />
      <div class="image_overlay"></div>
      <div id="view_details">Informationen
      </div>
      <div class="stats">
         <div class="stats-container">
            <span class="product_name">Acerola</span>    
            <p>Saftkonzentrat</p>
            <div class="product-options">
               <strong>Verfügbare Produkte</strong>
               <span>Acerolasaftkonzentrat (blank 42° Brix)</span>
               <strong>Verpackungsgrößen</strong>
               <div class="product-options">
                  <span>20 Kg Bag-in-Box (Aseptic)</span>
                  <span>200 Kg Fass (Aseptic)</span>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="product-back">
      <div class="shadow"></div>
      <div id="carousel">
         <div>
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <h3 class="informations">Informationen</h3>
                  <div>
                     <p class="product-desc">Acerolasaft-Konzentrat ist eine klare Flüssigkeit, die aus entpektinisiertem, gefiltertem, unvergorenem Fruchtsaft aus gesunden, sauberen Früchten durch physikalisches Abtrennen von Wasser hergestellt wird.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                     <p class="contact-text">Weitere Produktinformationen auf <a href="#">Anfrage</a></p>
                  </div>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="flip-back">
            <div id="cy"></div>
            <div id="cx"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have no idea why i not works... CSS:

```
/* Generals resets and unimportant stuff */
* { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
body {
    background: #eaebec;
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif; 
}


/* --- Product Card ---- */
#make-3D-space{
    position: relative;
    width:340px;
    height:500px;
    transition: transform 5s;
    position:absolute;
}
#product-front, #product-back{
    width:335px;
    height:500px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    left:-5px;
    top:-5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
}
#product-back{
    display:none;
    transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}
#product-card.animate #product-back, #product-card.animate #product-front{
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 100ms ease-out; 
}
#product-card{
    width:325px;
    height:470px;
    position:absolute;    
    top:10px;
    left:10px;  
    overflow:hidden;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
            transition:  100ms ease-out;
}
div#product-card.flip-10{
     -webkit-transform: rotateY( -10deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( -10deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( -10deg );
              transform: rotateY( -10deg );
               transition:  50ms ease-out;          
}
div#product-card.flip90{
     -webkit-transform: rotateY( 90deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 90deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 90deg );
              transform: rotateY( 90deg );
               transition:  100ms ease-in;          
}
div#product-card.flip190{
     -webkit-transform: rotateY( 190deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 190deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 190deg );
              transform: rotateY( 190deg );
               transition:  100ms ease-out;             
}
div#product-card.flip180{
     -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 180deg );
              transform: rotateY( 180deg );
               transition:  150ms ease-out;             
}
#product-card.animate{
    top:5px;
    left:5px;
    width:335px;
    height:500px;
    box-shadow:0px 13px 21px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -webkit-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition:  100ms ease-out; 
            transition:  100ms ease-out; 
}
.stats-container{
    background:#fff;    
    position:absolute;
    top:386px;
    left:0;
    width:265px;
    height:300px;
    padding:27px 35px 35px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}
#product-card.animate .stats-container{
    top:272px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
}

.product-desc {
  text-algin: center;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.contact-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.contact-button: {
    top:112px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-85px;  
    border:2px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:19px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:10px 0;
    width:172px;    
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
#view_details:hover{    
    background:#fff;
    color:#22aadd;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.informations {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.stats-container .product_name{
    font-size:22px;
    color:#393c45;  
}
.stats-container p{
    font-size:16px;
    color:#b1b1b3;  
    padding:2px 0 20px 0;
}
.stats-container .product_price{
    float:right;
    color:#48cfad;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:600;
}
.image_overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#22aadd;
    opacity:0;  
}
#product-card.animate .image_overlay{
    opacity:0.7;    
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.product-options{
    padding:2px 0 0;
}
.product-options strong{
    font-weight:700;
    color:#393c45;
    font-size:14px;
}
.product-options span{  
    color:#969699;
    font-size:14px;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:8px;
}
#view_details{  
    position:absolute;
    top:112px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-85px;  
    border:2px solid #fff;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:19px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:700;
    padding:10px 0;
    width:172px;    
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
#view_details:hover{    
    background:#fff;
    color:#22aadd;
    cursor:pointer;

}
#product-card.animate #view_details{
    opacity:1;
    width:152px;
    font-size:15px;
    margin-left:-75px;
    top:115px;
    -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
       -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
         -o-transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
            transition: all 200ms ease-out;         
}
div.colors div{
    margin-top:3px;
    width:15px; 
    height:15px;    
    margin-right:5px;
    float:left;
}
div.colors div span{
    width:15px; 
    height:15px; 
    display:block;
    border-radius:50%;
}
div.colors div span:hover{
    width:17px;
    height:17px;
    margin:-1px 0 0 -1px;
}
div.c-blue span{background:#6e8cd5;}
div.c-red span{background:#f56060;}
div.c-green span{background:#44c28d;}
div.c-white span{
    background:#fff;
    width:14px;
    height:14px; 
    border:1px solid #e8e9eb;
}
div.shadow{
    width:335px;height:520px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:3;
    display:none;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.2));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.1),rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0,0,0,0.2)); 
}
#product-back div.shadow{
    z-index:10;
    opacity:1;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,rgba(0,0,0,0.2),rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); 
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2), rgba(0,0,0,0.1)); 
}
#flip-back{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#cx, #cy{
    background:#d2d5dc;
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    top:15px;
    right:15px;
    height:3px;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
#flip-back:hover #cx, #flip-back:hover #cy{
    background:#979ca7;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
            transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
}
#cx.s1, #cy.s1{ 
    right:0;    
    width:30px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
#cy.s2{ 
    -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    transform: rotate(50deg);        
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
#cy.s3{ 
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform: rotate(45deg);        
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
#cx.s1{ 
    right:0;    
    width:30px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
#cx.s2{ 
    -ms-transform: rotate(140deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(140deg); 
    transform: rotate(140deg);       
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
#cx.s3{ 
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
    transform: rotate(135deg);       
    -webkit-transition: all 100ease-out;
       -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
        -ms-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
         -o-transition: all 100ms ease-out;
            transition: all 100ms ease-out;
}
#carousel{
    width:335px;
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;

}
#carousel ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
#carousel li{
    width:335px;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
.arrows-perspective{
    width:335px;
    height:55px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 218px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 5s;
    perspective: 335px;
}
.carouselPrev, .carouselNext{
    width: 50px;
    height: 55px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: absolute; 
    top:0;
    transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
    opacity:0.9;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.carouselNext{
    top:0;
    right: -26px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( -117deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( -117deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( -117deg );
              transform: rotateY( -117deg );
              transition: all 200ms ease-out;           

}
.carouselNext.visible{
        right:0;
        opacity:0.8;
        background: #efefef;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
.carouselPrev{      
    left:-26px;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY( 117deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 117deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 117deg );
              transform: rotateY( 117deg );
              transition: all 200ms ease-out; 

}
.carouselPrev.visible{
        left:0;
        opacity:0.8;
        background: #eee;
        -webkit-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
         -moz-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
           -o-transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transform: rotateY( 0deg );
              transition: all 200ms ease-out; 
}
#carousel .x, #carousel .y{
    height:2px;
    width:15px;
    background:#48cfad;
    position:absolute;
    top:31px;
    left:17px;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform: rotate(45deg);   
}
#carousel .x{
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
    transform: rotate(135deg);      
    top:21px;
}
#carousel .carouselNext .x{
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);   
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); 
    transform: rotate(45deg);       
}
#carousel .carouselNext .y{
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);  
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg); 
    transform: rotate(135deg);      
}

/* Button */

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.btn,
button {
  background: #1d1d1d;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 14px 21px;
  padding: 1.4rem 2.1rem;
  border: 2px solid #1d1d1d;
  transition: color 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.08, 0.355, 1), background 0.1s cubic-bezier(0.16, 0.08, 0.355, 1);
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-width: 20rem;
  outline: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .btn,
  button {
    width: auto;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .btn,
  button {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    padding: 1.6rem 2.8rem;
  }
}
.btn:hover,
button:hover {
  background: #2a2a2a;
  border-color: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-border {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #1d1d1d;
}
.btn-arrow {
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
}
.btn-arrow span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  will-change: transform;
}
.btn-arrow:hover span {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1rem, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(-1rem, 0, 0);
}
.btn-arrow svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1.1em;
  right: 0px;
  right: 0rem;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  will-change: right, opacity;
}
.btn-arrow svg * {
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-color: transparent;
}
.btn-arrow:hover svg {
  opacity: 1;
  right: -2rem;
}
```

And my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Lift card and show stats on Mouseover
    $('#product-card').hover(function(){
            $(this).addClass('animate');
            $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');            
         }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass('animate');         
            $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
    }); 

    // Flip card to the back side
    $('#view_details').click(function(){        
        $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').removeClass('visible');
        $('#product-card').addClass('flip-10');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip-10').addClass('flip90').find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 80 , 1, function(){
                $('#product-front, #product-front div.shadow').hide();          
            });
        }, 50);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip190');
            $('#product-back').show().find('div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 90 , 0);
            setTimeout(function(){              
                $('#product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip180').find('div.shadow').hide();                        
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#product-card').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');         
                    $('#cx, #cy').addClass('s1');
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#cx, #cy').addClass('s2');}, 100);
                    setTimeout(function(){$('#cx, #cy').addClass('s3');}, 200);             
                    $('div.carouselNext, div.carouselPrev').addClass('visible');                
                }, 100);
            }, 100);            
        }, 150);            
    });         

    // Flip card back to the front side
    $('#flip-back').click(function(){       

        $('#product-card').removeClass('flip180').addClass('flip190');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip190').addClass('flip90');

            $('#product-back div.shadow').css('opacity', 0).fadeTo( 100 , 1, function(){
                $('#product-back, #product-back div.shadow').hide();
                $('#product-front, #product-front div.shadow').show();
            });
        }, 50);

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#product-card').removeClass('flip90').addClass('flip-10');
            $('#product-front div.shadow').show().fadeTo( 100 , 0);
            setTimeout(function(){                      
                $('#product-front div.shadow').hide();
                $('#product-card').removeClass('flip-10').css('transition', '100ms ease-out');      
                $('#cx, #cy').removeClass('s1 s2 s3');          
            }, 100);            
        }, 150);            

    }); 
});
```

Maybe someone can help me to get five cards in a row.

Vielleicht schaut hier ja auch ein Deutscher drauf, ich möchte halt fünf Produkte  in eine Reihe bekommen. Das kann ich aber nicht weil sich das ganze dauerhaft überlappt. :(

Comment: Duplicate ids?  Where is your second card?

Comment: From Review: Please do not write your question in German on this website.

Comment: your code is for fliping the card and view details, not for creating new cards or showing cards if exists

Comment: @James just copy the <div id="make-3D-space"> DIV and paste it, normaly you can dublicate divs like this

Comment: When you get an element by id the browser returns the first one it finds.  If you want to refer to a group of similar elements you need to use class instead.  In your javascript handlers, use `this` to refer to the element that was clicked/hovered, like you do in your hover handler.

Comment: and how i can create more cards like the first?

Comment: You need to change your 'id based' design to something more 'class based' to be able to manage several cards. IdDs are supposed to be unique in the page. Also, your overlap problem comes from your absolute positionning use, logically making first displayed item disappear behind later ones.

Comment: you can use `.clone` function to make a copy  but your css is making it force to fixed position,

Comment: @ESN Can you help me please? i have no idea how to do that...

Comment: @AhmedSunny how can i fix that?